# Is a C# 7 tuple-based variable swap thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Before C# 7's tuples, the standard way to swap two variables was something like:

```
var foo = 5;
var bar = 10;

var temp = foo;
foo = bar;
bar = temp;
```

But now we can use

```
(foo, bar) = (bar, foo);
```

It's on one line and it's prettier. But is it thread safe - is the swap done atomically, or is this just sugar over top of a multi-step operation?

Comment: Single assignments aren't thread-safe, so it makes no difference that this is "multi-step".

Comment: If you need atomic operations you must use `Interlocked`, in this case `Interlocked.Exchange`

Comment: @maccettura Sorry. My question is about a capability of the language, and while I was writing code for a swap I wondered if the new tuple stuff had any implications for thread safety. I'm not asking for reasons to *not* swap variables, and I'm not actually in a thread-sensitive situation ATM. Just curious.

Comment: My guess is that copies the values into a value tuple then copies the values into the variables.  Basically the value tuple becomes the temp variable.  So I doubt it's atomic.

Comment: In your example those are all local variables. Another thread entering the same section would have it's own set of local variables on the stack. So there is no interference. It's a different story if foo and bar are object variables. In that case you need to use some sort of thread synchronization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-synchronization)

Comment: @Trioj context isn't important to know?  If the OP is swapping variables to solve a (as of now unknown) problem, and there is another method or process that would solve that problem in a better way, is it not helpful for us to know that?  I have never run into a situation where I have done this, so I wanted to know why the OP was in case it can be solved in another way.

Comment: No, it's on me. I apologize for being unfriendly and I'm enjoying the back and forth. :) @BenVoigt, can you expand on your comment about single assignment? I assumed it was always "last in wins" but no further complications.

Comment: @James: A single assignment can be split by the CPU into multiple memory operations, in no particular order, and with intermediate states possibly visible to other cores, depending on the size and alignment of the operands.  Now you are dealing with multiple memory locations separated by an arbitrary distance... how could that possibly be more atomic than the contiguous blocks case?

Comment: @maccettura If i ask you how to instantiate an object, you do not need to know what I am doing to point me to the new operator. Context isn't always important to know. Notice how Ben required no further information to provide his answers that are correct?

Comment: @Gusman: Unfortunately, `Interlocked.Exchange` only performs atomic access to one of the two variables, not the entire swap.

Comment: @James: Furthermore, this is a read-modify-write sort of operation, which isn't atomic even for primitive types.  (The thread-safe lock-free R/M/W for primitives involves `Interlocked.CompareExchange` in a retry-loop).

Comment: @JamesOrr I was on board with the contrived example, but Marc's response to my answer below does highlight how perhaps your example does not compile down to give the best answer. I do appreciate the simplicity in the question but I think in this case a real world example may be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks folks, this has been educational!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No, basically".

The `ValueTuple<...>` family are mutable value types, which makes it complex. The older `Tuple<...>` family were immutable reference types; the "immutable" matters because it means it isn't changing individual fields - it is creating a new object with *all* the values. The "reference-type" matters because this is then a single reference exchange which *is* thread-safe in as much as you can't get a "torn reference". It isn't thread-safe in other ways: there's no guarantees about ordering or registers, etc.

But with `ValueTuple<...>` even that is gone. Because it is a mutable type, this is most likely implemented as multiple `ldloca`/`ld...`/`stfld` instructions, so *even if* the value type is not larger than the CPU width, there's no guarantee that it will all be written in a single CPU instruction - and it almost certainly won't be. In the "return a value, assign the entire thing" scenario it *might* be a single CPU instruction if small enough, but it might not! To make it even more complex, *in addition* to the mutable field approach, there are *also* custom constructors - but they will still ultimately be writing over the same memory location (for value types, the destination managed reference is passed *into* the constructor, rather than the constructed value being passed *out*).

There is no guarantee whatsoever made by the language or runtime about tuple atomicity; they only make guarantees about references and certain primitives -additionally, *even if it was*: thread-safety is a *lot* more than just atomicity.

Finally, it would *also* depend don the target CPU; obviously a 2-int tuple **cannot** be atomic on a 32-bit CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Your first method compiles as:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Method1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2068
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32,
        [1] int32,
        [2] int32
    )

    // (no C# code)
    IL_0000: nop
    // int num = 5;
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    // int num2 = 10;
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0005: stloc.1
    // int num3 = num;
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: stloc.2
    // num = num2;
    IL_0008: ldloc.1
    IL_0009: stloc.0
    // num2 = num3;
    IL_000a: ldloc.2
    IL_000b: stloc.1
    // (no C# code)
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method Program::Method1
```

And your second method compiles as:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Method2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2084
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32,
        [1] int32,
        [2] int32
    )

    // (no C# code)
    IL_0000: nop
    // int num = 5;
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    // int num2 = 10;
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0005: stloc.1
    // int num3 = num2;
    IL_0006: ldloc.1
    // int num4 = num;
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: stloc.2
    // num = num3;
    IL_0009: stloc.0
    // num2 = num4;
    IL_000a: ldloc.2
    IL_000b: stloc.1
    // (no C# code)
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method Program::Method2
```

As you can see they both compile down slightly differently but effectively take similar steps to accomplish the same goal.

One calls Load-Store-Load-Store-Load-Store, where the other calls Load-Load-Store-Store-Load-Store.

The only interesting note here is that the tuple version allocates additional memory as it stores two items on the stack at one time, versus the first method which stores only a max of one item on the stack at any given time.

Comment: that is a debug build; it shouldn't be used when thread-safety matters; sharplab might be helpful: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvKgzoukgNiIAsBALIAKAJRsOXGQDcICAgA8CAXgKjiSAgCIIwAMY7xFSjLkKCATzUEA4nBgAVAK4AHDHAmnzXEgE5RJRNpXwDRKxCzLgBfUKJiflE0ADsYAgAzAHss7RJCYAVJB2d3Twk1AD4Nem0dABM4DONTGKA

Comment: it also looks like the compiler chose to completely erase the fact that tuples ever existed... making this not *perhaps* the clearest example :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, is it the initial nop instruction which lets you know it is Debug? I explored this on [sharplab.io][1] and that is an interesting way to investigate this. I was surprise to see that the old way seems to be better.


  [1]: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLAChUwMwAJ5YMJYDeqWpOccRJZNYAdsFgGYD2LWAvFgKwDc1NUvUYAjAIYAnTlgQAGfmhSCyMBAE4AFABIARKxYgi+gL4AaLOImHCl4zoCUC5aQDKAdzEAHDRICmTZjZzPwDLRwFBVU1dfWsTc0trWwcnZwAVAFdPCF93Lx9/QJZgwrDU5SjtPTY4tjMLSSTJO3ClMmMIiMwcBAA2HAAWLDzvEKxhLDESgImRewjiNuUJ4F8AW09pMXLBMWkRHZoRaVWNnY6lrC7sVX6YIczs3I9RwomprDHZ+cvF5ywNB85tINCJzGJWjQLsYgA

Comment: @Ryan yes, that's a big clue

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the previous answers...

No, not thread safe, BUT remember that each thread has its own local variables and unless you're swapping shared stuff you don't have to worry.

If you are swapping shared values then there are a number of techniques you can use to make it thread safe.  You can use locks.  You can put multiple variables into an object and swap the object atomically.  You can use a .NET concurrent container.  It depends upon the specifics of what you want to do.