# How does tuple assignment work in C# when swapping variables?

Tags: c#

When swapping 2 variables the traditional way, I need to create a temp variable. However, with tuples in C# the variables can just be 'magically' swapped. How does the tuple assignment work so that no values are lost?

// Old way

```
 var tmp = n;
 n = m;
 m = tmp;
```

// Tuple assignment

```
 (n, m) = (m, n);
```

Both ways produce the same result. Is this dealt with as a special case in the tuple class, or is it a byproduct of the way this class is generally implemented?

Comment: This answer kind of explains how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551987/2987253

Comment: I was about to post the IL as an answer. It's basically doing the same thing both ways.

Comment: @Loocid thanks for that link. It didn't come up in my search. Definitely helped my understanding.